# Flex Spark DataGrid GridItemEditorSessionSave Event issue

Tags: apache-flex

I have a strange problem in Flex `s:DataGrid/>`. The `gridItemEditorSessionSave` event triggers two times for me. The minimum code to recreate this issue is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="dp">
            <fx:Object test="Test"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.GridItemEditorEvent;

            protected function onGridItemEditorSessionSave(event:GridItemEditorEvent):void
            {
                trace("Edited >>>", event.columnIndex);
            }

            protected function onGridItemEditorSessionStart(event:GridItemEditorEvent):void
            {
                trace("Edit Start >>>", event.columnIndex);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}" width="100%" height="100%" editable="true"
                gridItemEditorSessionSave="onGridItemEditorSessionSave(event)"
                gridItemEditorSessionStart="onGridItemEditorSessionStart(event)">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="test"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

When I edit the cell, the trace statement is as below :

`Edit Start >>> 0
Edited >>> 0
Edited >>> 0`

Which indicates `onGridItemEditorSessionSave` triggers twice! Not sure I am missing anything.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like a bug. There are other reports for this : http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/spark-Datagrid-GridItemEditorEvent-firing-twice-td3582.html

As mentioned in this discussion I have done a workaround by setting a flag `_goForCellEdit=true` in the `ItemListEditStart` event and checked this in `gridItemEditorSessionSave` event. Hope will help if some one ran into the same problem.